# Reopen previously deleted Google account

Tags: google-account, account-management, account-recovery

I closed one Gmail account and opened another. I foolishly deleted everything from previous account. I now need information of a transaction I made.

Can I reopen previous account and recover emails?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: *Maybe*

Google [has a support page for recovering a deleted Google account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295). Here's the salient information from that page:

> If you [deleted your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046), you have a short amount of time to try to recover it. You can then sign in with this account to Gmail, Google Play, and other Google products.
>
> To see if you can recover your account:
>
> - Visit the [password assistance](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/) page.
> - Select **I'm having other problems signing in**.
> - Follow the steps on the screen to verify your identity and attempt to restore your account.

They do not define what a "short amount of time" is. This is the only way to recover a deleted Google account and, if you've missed your window, the account is essentially gone forever.